# Upgrade from Windows Phone 8.0 Development to Windows Phone 8.1 Development

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I am Developing Apps on "Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 For Windows Phone". I develop Windows Phone 8.0 Apps.

Now I need to develop Windows Phone 8.1 Apps free. Which Visual Studio to use for this purpose.? and What about windows Phone 8.1 Emulator.

If possible share both download links.

Comment: for 8.1 you need VS 2013. If possible google "download windows phone sdk 8.1" yourself

Answer (score 2):

You Should use `Visual Studio 2013`. here is a download link for [Express 2013 for Windows](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) 
that can be used for windows and windows phone as well as Universal Apps. for windows phone 8.1 emulators, you can download them from here [Windows Phone 8.1 Emulators](http://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/download-phone-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

To develop Windows Phone 8.1 App, You should use ***Visual Studio 2013***.

And here is the download link: [Visual Studio Downloads](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs)

Comment: and what about Emulators?

Comment: Can i keep both "Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 For Windows Phone" and "Visual Studio 2013" installed on PC. or Visual Studio 2013 will serve the purpose of both?

Comment: The Visual Studio 2013 contains Windows Phone 8.1 SDK, which contains Windows Phone Emulator.

Comment: Yes, you can install both VS2012 and VS2013. And you can also develop WP8.0 app with VS2013.

Answer (score 0):

On the [**Dev Center**](http://dev.windows.com/en-us) of Microsoft you can find all information, samples and tools you need to develop Windows and Windows Phone apps.

Info from the site regarding to WP development:

**Windows Phone 8.1 development tools:**

> The Windows Phone 8.1 development tools are installed with Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows with Update 2 and Visual Studio 2013 Update 2.

**Windows Phone 8.1 Emulators:**

> This package requires Visual Studio 2013 with Update 2 or later, Windows 8.1 (x64) Professional edition or higher, and a processor that supports Client Hyper-V and Second Level Address Translation (SLAT).

Here are several links to useful parts of the site:

- [**Downloads**](http://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/downloads) (scroll to Windows Phone section)
- [**SDK**](http://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/download-phone-sdk)

*Note:* with these tools, you can still develop Windows Phone 8.0 apps as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Option in visual studio 2013 express from [here](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-express-windows-8).

**Edit:**

After Installation open your windows phone 8.0 project in visual studio 2013 fallow the process described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn642081(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_UpgradeyourWindowsPhone8apptoSilverlight81). As same as windows phone 8 emulators will comes under windows phone Sdk

[image]

Check this link about [Documention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn642081(v=vs.105).aspx).

**Note:**
I suggest you to **back up of your windows phone 8.0 project to separate Folder to continue the development of windows phone 8.0**.

**Why:**

You cannot downgrade a upgraded app with version 8.1 to version 8 or 7.1.

All the Best.